# AlarmReceiver working in incoming call android

Tags: android, android-manifest, alarmmanager

i have alarm service that listin to android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE and it work good but when i have incoming call it start my alarm.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incoming call is a change in phone state, so naturally that triggers your alarm if you've set your alarm service to trigger an alarm on that intent.

Take a look at [EXTRA_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_STATE). That might help you filter down exactly when you should trigger your alarm.